# Как в списочном массиве ArrayList сделать проверку

Tags: java

Интересует как именно сделать проверку есть ли в этом списке значения диапазона от 30 до 60 к примеру, и что бы эта проверка выводила к примеру "есть, их 10" или "Нет, 0".

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class newClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> numbers  = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            numbers.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Количество считается так:

```
numbers.stream().filter(x -> x > 30 && x < 60).count()
```

Comment: А как с этого вывести количество?

Comment: Как вы и делаете -  через System.out.println(...);

Comment: Все понял, я просто не так все поставил